# GitKraken repository user and password mistakenly remembered

Tags: git, gitkraken

By mistake, when I want to clone a repository, I entered an incorrect username and password and I clicked the button "remember me", so now I cannot change the key because whenever I redo, the clone keeps the wrong data saved.

Where can I delete this data?

[image]

Comment: I don't know how to reproduce this behaviour... when I try to give wrong credential the first time, it refuses the connexion. Did you consider uninstalling Gitkraken completely?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It feels a bit like over kill when I only want to change one password, but I the answer seems to be to:
File Menu > Preferences > Authentication > Forget all Usernames and Passwords

https://support.gitkraken.com/integrations/authentication/#forget-all

Comment: I think the Authentication menu was removed and the "Forget all Usernames and Passwords" is in the general section: https://support.gitkraken.com/integrations/authentication/

Comment: The menu said no use and psw in local